# Ignorar el bearer token para dicha peticion

Tags: java, spring

Estoy generando un ***Bearer token*** a través de un método **GetMapping** , el tema es que tengo puesta mi seguridad para que cada petición se tenga que hacer con un Bearer Token , ¿cómo puedo hacer para que solo esta petición se pueda hacer una petición sin seguridad , es decir sin el bearer token?

He tratado de hacerlo con `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/rest/authorization/token");` pero así no funciona

Mi clase de Security:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(value = {UnauthorizedRestEntryPoint.class, CustomJWTAuthFilter.class})
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        @Autowired
        private CustomJWTAuthFilter customJWTAuthFilter;
        
        @Autowired
        private UnauthorizedRestEntryPoint unauthorizedRestEntryPoint;
        
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                //.antMatcher("/rest/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(customJWTAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedRestEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
            
            
        }
    }
    
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AppWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http,WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
            
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/rest/authorization/token");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con:

```java
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/authorization/token").permitAll()
```

Es decir agregalo a tu config:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http         
 .authorizeRequests()
 .antMatchers("/rest/authorization/token").permitAll()
 .anyRequest().authenticated()
 .and()
 .addFilterBefore(customJWTAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
 .exceptionHandling()
 .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedRestEntryPoint)
 .and()
 .csrf().disable();   
}
```